# how to create custom UI like pulse in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to crate a Custom UI similar to pulse android app. As I understand, to start with I have to first create a custom button as shown on the below image marked.

[image]

My button has an image and text overlay on it. I know it is a basic question, but I am facing this issue, as I am a beginner to android development. Please do help me to understand how to go with this.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You are asking how to make a button with text on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Now about the part with grid integration: save the XML content of the example above (RelativeLayout + ImageView + TextView), into a new XML file, let it be `layout/grid_item.xml`.
Add a unique `id` for the `ImageView` and `TextView`

Then in the `getView()` method of your adapter inflate that layout and find the ImageView and TextView by id, and set appropriate content.

Note, this is not full source code, but a basic scheleton should look like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ....
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    ....

    ImageView myImage=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_image);
    TextView myTextView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);

    myImage.setImageResource(...);
    myTextView.setText(...);
    ...

    return convertView
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could compose a simple layout from an `ImageView` and a `TextView` aligned to the bottom with black text and some transparency. Both views should be placed inside a `RelativeLayout.` Then you set a click listener for the `RelativeLayout` and take appropriate action on click.

Ex:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/my_test_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#4000"
        android:text="Giorgio Armany Galaxy S"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your program:

```
RelativeLayout item=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
    item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // take action
        }
});
```

This is one scenario. Another scenario is to extend the `Button` and compose your custom UI component if you would like, which will involve some more coding but instead you'll have a unique component.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It works exactly as expected. Now if the same I have to implement with grid view how could i do it. I got the below link, but it is for simple images. how i cam make it done for this custom view? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html