# GridView with text on images on android and Data structure design in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

1.I like to know how to add text (can change in the future) each image as shown in this picture
http://developer.android.com/design/media/accessibility_contentdesc.png

2.I want to build a data structure so that each day will add on something like 20 pictures with a little more information
Should I build a single table that will hold all days. And in this table I produce the relevant days Or table per day? it's matter?

thanks and advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar question, take a look at both answers on this thread: [how to create custom UI like pulse in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775017/how-to-create-custom-ui-like-pulse-in-android/11777794#11777794)

First read the second answer, and only then move up to the accepted answer, as the accepted answer is a continuation of the second.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show text on your ImageView you should create an xml layout which contains an ImageView and a TextView that you will inflate in the getView lethod of your GridView adapter.
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(viewid);